# Find a line with a single word and merge it with the next line

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, tr

I have an issue with grep that i can't sort out.

**What I have**.
A listing of firstnames and lastnames, like:

```
John Doe
Alice Smith
Bob Smith
```

**My problem**.
Sometimes, firstname and lastname are disjointed, like:

```
Alice
Smith
Bob Doolittle
Mark
Von Doe //sometimes, there are more than one word on the next line
```

**What I'd like to achieve**.
Concatenate the "orphan" name with the next line.

```
Alice Smith
Bod Doolittle
Mark Von Doe
```

**What I already tried**

```
grep -ozP "^\w+\n\w.+" file | tr '\n' ' '
```

So, here I ask grep to find a line with just one word and concatenate it with the following line, even is this next line has more than one word.

It works correctly but only if the isolated word is at the very beginning of the file. **If it appears below the first line, grep do not spot it**. So a quick and dirty solution where I would loop through the file and remove a line after each pass doesn't work for me.

Comment: What about people who only use 1 name? https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: That's something to take in consideration in many cases, indeed, but here that can't happen. The names in the listing come from a national registry where you can't go without at least one firstname and one lastname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `awk` is acceptable:

```
awk '
NF==1 {printf "%s ",$1; getline; print; next}
1' names.dat
```

Where:

- `NF==1` - if only one name/field in the current record ...
- `printf / getline / print / next` - print field #1, read next line and print it, then skip to next line
- `1` - print all other lines as is

As a one-liner:

```
awk 'NF==1{printf "%s ",$1;getline;print;next}1' names.dat
```

This generates:

```
Alice Smith
Bob Doolittle
Mark Von Doe //sometimes, there are more than one word on the next line
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU `sed` like this:

```sh
sed -E -i '/^[^[:space:]]+$/{N;s/\n/ /}' file
```

See [the `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/NVTtCI):

```sh
s='Alice
Smith
Bob Doolittle
Mark
Von Doe //sometimes, there are more than one word on the next line'
sed -E '/^[^[:space:]]+$/{N;s/\n/ /}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Alice Smith
Bob Doolittle
Mark Von Doe //sometimes, there are more than one word on the next line
```

Details:

- `/^[^[:space:]]+$/` finds a line with no whitespace
- `{N;s/\n/ /}` - reads in the next line, and appends a newline char with this new line to the current pattern space, and then `s/\n/ /` replaces this newline char with a space.

Comment: Even if I will go with the awk solution, I wanted to thank you for your help: your one-liner helped me to solve another use case where I used sed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '
    {f=$2 ? 1 : 0}
    v==1{v=0; print; next} 
    f==0{v=1; printf "%s ", $1; next}
    1
' file
```

### Output

```
Alice Smith
Bob Doolittle
Mark Von Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN { $is_first_name = 1; } if ( @F == 1 && $is_first_name ) { @prev = @F; $is_first_name = 0; } else { print join " ", @prev, @F; $is_first_name = 1; @prev = (); }' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;s/^(\S+)\n/\1 /;P;D' file
```

Append the next line.

If the first line in the pattern space contains one word only, replace the following newline with a space.

Print/delete the first line and repeat.